Properties are not passed to docker-compose
The point is, I want to deploy my project to Docker, and the project consists of several microservices, in Docker Compose the configuration of Keycloak is described, and if you run the application on localhost, it easily connects to Keycloak via localhost. So now there is a need to configure my application in Docker, in Docker it should access Keycloak not via localhost, but via the container name. I am trying to build the application on this configuration:
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/task
  application:
    name: task-service
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: task-client
            client-secret: [redacted]
            scope: openid, profile
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/task-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs

Moreover, the build requires that keycloak be launched, otherwise the build will not be assembled. And then in docker-compose I redefine these connection URLs to the URLs of the docker containers.
 task:
    image: task-service
    container_name: task-service
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/task
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://eureka-server:8090/eureka
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_PROVIDER_KEYCLOAK_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_JWK_SET_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST=vhost
    depends_on:
      - eureka
      - mongodb
      - keycloak
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - task-management

When "docker-compose up" task-service crashes with errors because I can't connect to keycloak because it tries to connect via localhost, although I redefine keycloak in docker-compose. I have the same problem with Open Feign Client It can't start because it can't find the service it refers to. Can anyone tell me what I'm redefining incorrectly. For example, when I redefine mongo url, it is redefined
I expect help with overriding property of configuration beans of keycloak

What do the logs say ?

Logs of task-service:
1)Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused

And  caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm"

I just create a jar with keyckloack property, and now service trying to acces keycloak, but with exception

How do you reference your environment varialbles in your application.yml ?

dependson might not be sufficient, maybe you need to make sure all containers are up and running, because starting task service containers start

Keycloak container started, and if i will try to start my app just on localhost, it will connect to keycloak, but throw the container no

in application.yml i changed all url like this:
issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm

NEVER EVER share a real secret on a public forum. I would recommend immediately invalidating that client secret. I've edited the post to remove it, but it is still available in the edit history.

man relax, its a pet project

If configuration is correct, ports references, and all environment variables are correctly references, you should probably add a healthcheck before starting all containers, dependson might not be enough:
version: '3.8'

This is the example just to show healthcheck service for mongoDb and keycloak, but it should be done the same way for all the others required by task container:

  #just an example please use yours.
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mongo", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  #just an example please use yours.
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - '8180:8080'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5


  task-service:
    image: task-service
    container_name: task-service
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/task
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://eureka-server:8090/eureka
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_PROVIDER_KEYCLOAK_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_JWK_SET_URI=http://keycloak:8180/auth/realms/task-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST=vhost
    depends_on:
      eureka:
        condition: service_healthy
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - task-management

networks:
  task-management:
    driver: bridge


keycloak is healthy
but task-service not started and waiting

But now its unhealthy, how i can just make healthy?

Every service has different type of healthcheck. The healthcheck is just to make sure instance is started.
